# exception doesn't get caught within try/catch func delegate

Tags: c#, azure-data-explorer

I'm attempting to use a re-usable try/catch for executing Kusto queries in C# like so:

```
public static T DoWithRetry<T>(Func<T> func, TimeSpan sleepPeriod, int tryCount = 3)
        {
            if (tryCount <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(tryCount));

            while(true)
            {
                try
                {
                    return func();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    if (--tryCount == 0)
                        throw;
                    Console.WriteLine($"Encountered exception {ex.Message}");
                    Console.WriteLine($"Retrying in {sleepPeriod}...");
                    Thread.Sleep(sleepPeriod);
                }
            }            
        }
```

And then calling it like so:

```
try 
{

    var res = DoWithRetry(() =>
    {
       return kustoClient.ExecuteQuery($"KustoQuery");
    }, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3));
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.Error.WriteLine($"Exception Message: {ex.Message}");
    return "failed, please check.";
}
```

**Edited to include outer try/catch in example**

However when Kusto throws a throttle exception, the exception is never caught inside the DoWithRetry try/catch, instead the outer try/catch. If I were to throw my own exception in the lambda like so:

```
var res = DoWithRetry(() =>
{
   throw new KustoRequestThrottledException();
}, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3));
```

it is caught within the DoWithRetry try/catch.
What could be preventing the kusto exception from being caught within the DoWithRetry try/catch?

Comment: @SadlyFullStack:
That's true, I want the tryCount to default to 3. Because 3 is not less than or equal to 0 in this case, it should not throw the exception until the while loop has been entered 3 times.
Edit: Sorry I might've misread your comment. The out of bounds exception is just for ensuring a valid tryCount is supplied when calling DoWithRetry. The kustoClient.ExecuteQuery eventually throws a throttle exception during a loop in my service, but that doesn't get caught in this example.

Comment: @BurnsBA: What's interesting is that in my code there is another outer try/catch block which wraps all of the kusto query executions. The exception gets caught there whenever the throttle occurs, somehow bypassing the try/catch in this example.

Comment: I'm curious, if your catch within DoWithRetry was generic (no Exception ex) like outer exception, would it catch?

Comment: @Adam: I actually investigated that due to another SO post (can't find the link anymore..) made me think the exception wasn't compliant, so I needed the generic catch {}. But actually my outer exception catches with Exception ex (will update in example). I also tested the inner try/catch with just catch {} ,but that didn't work either.

Comment: The other thought I had is maybe the system does not like the Thread.Sleep() within the catch block. What happens if you move this call to outside the catch block?
(On a side note, I would not recommend using Thread.Sleep(). Better would be to use a wait handle that is externally accessible in case outer method needs to abort retry attempts.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the execution of the query doesn't occur until the data is accessed later (In my case, I pass IDataReader into another function and perform .Read()). I ended up passing in the function which performs that read in the try/catch instead.